# How to get text from Tkinter Text widget in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a simple GUI code using `tkinter` in `Jupyter`:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
text = Text(root, width = 40, height = 15)
text.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

How can I get user inputted text?
If I add `text.get('1.0', 'end')` to the end of that code, it does not work, also when I add `text.get('1.0', 'end')` to another cell it doesn't start executing until I close the `root` window and after that it gives an error.
Like this:

```
In[1]: from tkinter import *
       root = Tk()
       text = Text(root, width = 40, height = 15)
       text.pack()
       root.mainloop()
```

```
In[2]: text.get('1.0', 'end')
```

`In[2]` does not start executing until I close the `Tk()` window, and after closing the window and start running `In[2]` it gives this error:

```
TclError: invalid command name ".!text"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot interact with a `tkinter mainloop` from the `ipython` interactive.
If you add a get text button, pressing it will retrieve the text widget content:

Like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root, width=40, height = 15)
text.pack()
tk.Button(root, text='get text', command=lambda: print(text.get('1.0', tk.END))).pack()
root.mainloop()
```